# Wikipedia style notice and warning markup?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, post-notices

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104064/run-php-script-from-python) which is nearly an exact duplicate of another. Would it be possible to make certain CSS elements available to editors so that certain edits can be quickly and easily differentiated from the original question?

Messages that could appear in such boxes are:

- **Your question is almost an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please consider revising your question to indicate why answers to the duplicate do not fit your need.**
- **Your question appears to be purely subjective in nature, please consider adding specific technical elements to your question.**
- **Your question is inflamatory and may be closed quickly unless it is revised**

... Or, others.

This strongly differentiates the views of the Stack Overflow community from the original poster and helps nudge poorly written questions into well written questions, when possible.

Additionally, if someone uses this special markup (maybe %$ ... message ... %$), the user sees a new comment from "so-community".

Sorry if this has been raised before, I did not find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support for banners?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We already do duplicate searches based on the title you give.
2. We do searches already based on subjectivity in the title.
3. If George Carlin was alive he would cry.

Comment: 4. The ability to make these comments already exists. This feature is called *comments*.

Answer (score 3):

This is now implemented in several ways:

- Duplicate notices are given blockquote formatting to make them stand out, and are added automatically to duplicate questions
- Closed posts have a notification box explaining why they were closed and what users should do
- Locked posts are now required to show a [reason for the post lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/better-handling-of-locked-questions-and-answers)
- There are several [post notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners) that can be added by moderators, including "needs citations", "rapidly changing event", and "looking for canonical answers". There may eventually be support for arbitrary mod messages on posts.

Although not implemented exactly as envisioned when this feature was proposed 2 years ago, this feature is essentially completed now.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, but not sure if "editor only" formatting is really possible on SO.

Bold text is now allowed in comments. So just post a big fat all-bold comment saying that. Or edit it in at the top of the question, maybe in a blockquote box...