# How did judaism.stackexchange.com get a disclaimer on the sidebar?

Tags: support, design, legal, sidebar

When I go to [judaism.stackexchange.com](http://judaism.stackexchange.com) I see the following on the right side nav:

[image: Screenshot]

> Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information you find here as if it came from a crowd of your friends.

How did they get that disclaimer? Is that a developer function? Who does one contact if they think such a disclaimer could be useful on another site? (Perhaps a site one might, hypothetically, be a pro-tem moderator on? Just out of curiosity, of course. Purely academic. Can't think of anywhere that would be useful on, nor any pro-tem mods who might be interested...)

Comment: Related: [Wanted: A standard way for a site to have a prominent professional advice disclaimer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104821)

Comment: Awesome, **Thanks Tim!** But, why does [CogSci](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) not have that?

Comment: I *believe* that it's dev-added text on a case-by-case basis, which I suppose you could request on your per-site meta (and/or by supporting the above-linked feature request).

Comment: Well, one could *hypothetically* ask on one's *hypothetical* per-site meta. It *is* an academic question... ;-)

Comment: @TheUnhandledException - CogSci is an academic discipline, anyone can do some research and start posting advice and information.  In other areas, like law, finance, and medicine, distributing advice as if you were a lawyer, CPA, or medical doctor can get you in trouble (IANAL), and acting as a rabbi has similar problems within the Jewish community.  Unless there's some certification for CogSci that I'm unaware of, you don't have any need for this disclaimer.

Comment: @Kevin: This was a hypothetical question; I haven't asked my fellow Cog Sci mods nor the community if they even want such a notice. That said, to address your comment, CogSci.SE encompasses both Psychology and Psychiatry, and I can easily argue that both of those are disciplines of medicine/require a degree so a disclaimer stating "this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly medical) advice" would be easily as needed on CogSci as Judaism.

Comment: Check out [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/wanted-a-standard-way-for-a-site-to-have-a-prominent-professional-advice-discla) and its answer for why this is not more widespread/automatic.

Answer (score 10):

Mi Yodeya (Judaism) was an SE 1.0 site that migrated to 2.0 (the current platform).  The 1.0 site had that disclaimer, which was initially lost on migrating to 2.0.  The notice in the screen shot in this question was added after a request to a community manager (Robert Cartaino).

The notice went away again upon graduation.  We were able to restore it a few years later after [we noticed that Law and Health had gotten disclaimers](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3883/472).  In all cases, the request came from moderators with a strong argument and community support.  SE doesn't want to plaster disclaimers all over every site, but for those fields where professionals might face legal, ethical, or financial disincentives if they dispense advice on the Internet (definitely [a concern](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/414/472) for rabbis), getting such a notice is possible.