# Proposal: Modify the "Current Event" post notice

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, post-notices

I'd like to propose a change to the "Current Event" post notice.

[image]

[It's not really well-defined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean), and in its current form it's somewhat limiting.

Rather than "Post is related to a rapidly changing event", I propose "Answers to this post are likely to change or become irrelevant over time".

The limitation of the current version was brought to light recently in a Meta question on the Christianity site: "[Questions that may require updating every few years](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5930/)"

The proposed version would allow it to be used for items including current events as well as those that change over time.  It seems to me that this would be beneficial for just about every StackExchange site.  We all have questions where one answer is relevant now, but a different answer becomes the best answer later.

Comment: There is another usage for this notice: when a post gets a lot of attention for whatever reason. For example, lets say someone is offering a service, say, an online marketplace, which is offering trade in illegal goods, say, drugs, and the owner posts post a question on a SE site, say, Stack Overflow, about technology to enable said illegal service, say, TOR, which then helps to lead some people, say, the FBI, to apprehend the poster, then all of that might generate a lot of (media) attention surrounding the post... I don't know how often this happens, though...