# Scroll to the sides in mobile when question has many tags

Tags: bug, tags, design, mobile-web, responsive-design

I've reproduced this behaviour in different communities, so it's very likely to be a general problem. I'm using Google Chrome in both Android and Windows 10.

When the question has a big list of tags, we then become able to scroll to the sides as well. Take for example [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean)

In Windows 10 using Chrome's Toggle device toolbar option in Galaxy S5 (the same happens in other devices like Pixel 2, iPhone X, ...)

[image: Scroll to the sides in mobile dev tools]

In Android using Chrome

[image: Scroll to the sides in mobile]

Comment: Can't reproduce for me the tags overflow to several lines as expected. Please tell what browser/OS you have.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask just edited the question