# What happened to the normal question status box?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Why was the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners) status box changed from the normal one to this one?

[image: Screenshot of the "migrated from" box]

It has one missing space, and the date is changed from the old style to this one. Why was it changed? Could we get the old one back?

Comment: This looks like a bug.

Comment: This seems to happen on every question with a "migrated" banner on it.

Comment: Also shouldn't that be `closed by 1,2,3,4,5` **at** `<date time>`? Not to mention, there is no Month 14 :p

Comment: This happens for [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545983/how-to-build-a-jsp-page-using-database-enteries), [merged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308828/in-visual-studio-2010-how-do-i-quickly-switch-from-a-h-file-to-the-correspondin), [locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513203/automatic-approve-new-register-user) and [deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545626/hindi-speech-recognizer-code-in-java) questions, too.

Comment: @Sathya This is the strange middle-endian date notation they are using in the US.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Formats and units of measure are a *solved problem*. There are [international standards](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html).

Comment: @Sklivvz Yeah, of course. It used to work already in the ISO 8601 format, and it likely broke because of some bug which caused some library default (this strange US date format) to be used instead of the ISO one.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann ditto on Protected questions

Comment: @Sklivvz, [right](http://articles.cnn.com/1999-09-30/tech/9909_30_mars.metric_1_mars-orbiter-climate-orbiter-spacecraft-team?_s=PM:TECH) ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a bug from a larger change this morning, I'll fix it when back at a computer in an hour or so

*Update:* this is now fixed and deployed.