# Move position of post notices on answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, post-notices

Back in September last year, Stack Exchange [implemented Post Notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners) (a.k.a. banners or "moderator comments").

They were in a response to requests from Skeptics.SE, and were originally expected to be mainly useful for Skeptics.SE. Certainly, they have been [popular at Skeptics.SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed), now tagging around 6% of answers!

However, they have been adopted by other sites, such as [UX.SE](https://ux.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed).

Now, we have had follow-up requests, asking for the appearance of the post notices to change - in particular, their current location.

- On Skeptics, there is strong support for the banner on an answer to appear *[above the answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/change-the-caveat-banner-on-posts)*. The argument is that such a caveat should be understood *before* a reader digests an answer, and also to avoid it being completely overlooked.
- (I [suggested a middle-ground compromise](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1498/23), in case the above option did not meet general approval. It did *not* get a lot of support from Skeptics.SE, but did inspire a script to prototype its appearance.)
- Meanwhile, over an UX, there is [a milder suggestion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/785/move-moderator-comment-banners) that has also seen strong support: that the notices be moved *above* the comments, closer to the answer.

Please move the post notices above the answer, or failing that, please adopt one of the other suggestions.

Comment: +1, I've always wondered why the notices were not at the top.

Comment: Yeah, it usually looks very out of place where it appears now. Hard to tell if it applies to the answer below or above. +1.

Comment: @jadarnel27: It's not put at the top because (when added to the question text at the top, which is the way we used to do it) it takes up *summary space*; every question on the "Top Questions" page would say *"This question is here for historical reasons, but it is not on-topic."* Not a very good effect. In addition, Google places more weight on text at the top of a page. In short, it's not quite that simple.

Comment: @Robert, is "Best Of" the same as "Greatest Hits"? This request is for post-notices on *answers* not questions, which I believe addresses your first concern.

Comment: Well, post notices on answers are broken (the wording is the same for questions), and the only **answer** I've actually seen a post notice on is [Bobince's legendary answer to the Parse Html with Regex question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102937) Moving answer post notices to the top makes no sense to me; it divorces such notices from the answer.  I would support moving such notices to the **top of the answer.**

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think he means moving answer post notices to right above the answer, not to the top of the entire page.

Comment: @jadarnel27: That's not what his last paragraph says.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Apologies for the silly mix-up. I meant above the answer. Corrected.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The post notices can be on either Questions or Answers. I am pretty sure Oddthinking meant "Right above the post"

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  If it can be done without breaking Google SEO, I'm all for it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - that's true for notices on **Questions** but not notices on **Answers** which is what this question is about.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples of answers with post notices [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/annotated-posts?tab=noticed) (link also appears in the question).

Comment: On Skeptics... Does anyone find that surprising at all? :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey Re "*it takes up summary space*" - Wouldn't that just be in the case of the old-style, "historical significance" notes within a post?  I wouldn't think the text would show in the summary when using the actual "add notice" functionality.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Yes, but Google works the same way, more or less, and it scans the entire page, not just the posts.  The old way, we got used to inserting it at the bottom of the post text, which is the same position that was chosen for the new post notice.

Comment: @Robert: As a skeptic who values being able to check people's claims for myself, I am disappointed that adoption hasn't spread to answers on the other sites. Give me a diamond for a day on virtually any of the SE sites, and I'll show you hundreds of examples there too! ;-)

Comment: @Oddthinking: On SO, our larger problem is people who post references without context (aka bare links). Code is it's own reference; it either works or it doesn't. *[Gratuitous "Science; it Works, Bitches" quote goes here]*

Comment: Put this on the list of reasons for making *special questions* (old, with post notices, etc) look **visually dissimilar** than others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The UX suggestion](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/785/move-moderator-comment-banners) was [implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233473/why-are-the-on-hold-closed-etc-banners-above-the-comments-now/233474#233474).

Answer (score 13):

Just to repeat the rationale from my original request on meta.skeptics.SE:

It’s not only so that the notice is seen *before* reading the answer, it’s so **that the notice is seen *at all*.** At the moment, it is in practice all too easy to overlook a notice completely. This couldn’t necessarily be anticipated beforehand (although some have argue this from the beginning) but now that we’ve had some time to evaluate the feature and I think it’s clear that the positioning is indeed detriment to noticeability.

While this could (to some extent) be mitigated by making it visually more prominent, I still think that putting it on top is both a superior solution and more logical.

Comment: Sorry, Konrad, for misrepresenting your original reason. I have edited the meta-question to include this.

Comment: @Oddthinking I didn’t actually think of it as a misrepresentation.

Comment: Particularly if an answer has loads of comments - currently you have to read the answer, look over all the comments and finally see the post notice at the end stating 'this is subjective....' which looks like it's associated to the answer below it not the answer way above it. - See [this example from ux.se](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/23317/3865)