# The "add comment" link is too close to the bounty notice, at least on beta sites

Tags: bug, design, post-notices

Now that [post notices have been shifted above the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233474/224428), the "add comment" link on is too close to the bounty notice on posts with bounties and 0 comments.

[image]

The "add comment" link could do with a few more pixels of whitespace above it. You can see this behavior at [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3202/1908). Note that the "add comment" link is adequately spaced for duplicate notices (and, I assume, other closure notices) - see [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5375/how-can-naruto-characters-teleport-disappear):

[image]