# How to best implement a "sources are required" policy?

Tags: discussion, moderation, per-site-meta

In a Stack Exchange site I am active in (Mythology), we've discussed [requiring reputable sources in all answers](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/264/62) (for obvious quality reasons).

Right now, the consensus we've reached seems to be:

1. Answers without sources are usually bad
2. Comment on answers without sources or answers that otherwise don't
   answer the question
3. Revisit the issue of requiring sources when we have more activity
   (and it gets harder for individual users to keep track of answers
   without sources).

When we revisit the issue, I would like to have more information about how other sites have implemented sources-are-required policies. Specifically, I'm interested in having the following questions answered:

1. How many sites take moderation action when answers are posted without sources (the one I'm most familiar with is [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)). What form does this action take (is the post removed, is a post notice added, etc.)
2. How many sites take unofficial action on answers without sources (i.e. downvotes, comments linking to a meta answer, etc.)?
3. When is it a good idea to transition from taking unofficial action to taking official action on answers without sources?
4. How much addition work does a sources policy create for moderators?
5. Does a "sources are required" policy significantly increase the quality of answers? In other words, is it worth the time to implement one?
6. What are the downsides to a sources-are-required policy?

Comment: Kind of related: http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1113/83

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm a Skeptics moderator, our policy is essentially that references for all significant claims are required and we remove answers that violate this rule. In some cases we delete answers outright, in others we add a "citation needed" notice and give the poster a chance to add some references. If that doesn't happen, the post is deleted after a while (this is the theory, we don't always remember to do that). Deleting immediately is mostly for answers that can't be fixed by adding a reference, those are mostly anecdotal answers or answers that are based on original research.

Skeptics is an outlier in the SE network, and while I generally think that encouraging users to add references to their answers, I don't think other sites need a citation policy as strict as ours. The citation policy is very hard on new users, it leads to considerable friction and can easily frustrate users that had their answers deleted. It is necessary on Skeptics due to our scope and the fact that we can't have experts on our site for everything, but that is not true for most other SE sites.

I would start with mostly informal actions, getting the community to downvote and comment on unsourced answers would be pretty good already. You could also use post notices on unsourced posts that get challenged in comments. Before you can even consider a Skeptics-style citation requirement you need a pretty strong community consensus. It took over a year for Skeptics to arrive at the point where we started deleting uncited posts.

Answer (score 9):

Ok, brain dump of a moderator (and very active user on Workplace, where we have similar concerns).

First, don't treat symptoms - the root cause is poor question quality and a community ok with poor quality answers. A clear question  is a lot easier to answer meaningfully than a bad one. Take care to close poor questions first, this will help a ton.

[Downvote poor quality answers](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1627/2322) and suggest improvements. Some people will be hopeless, sure. But most people writing answers *like* it and want to be helpful. But most of the Internet is a barren wasteland though, where you drop thoughts and don't have to bother with explaining why.

> How many sites take moderation action when answers are posted without sources (the one I'm most familiar with is Skeptics). What form does this action take (is the post removed, is a post notice added, etc.)

My rule of thumb is, "if you don't explain *why* you would do this, it's not backed up." This can be a variety of forms. Oftentimes on Workplace, it's just explaining why. [This meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/511/2322) probably sums my perspective up the best I can think of.

Regarding actions, generally a post notice and a comment (the Workplace community does a great job with this, mods rarely have to do this) serve to be sufficient. Though in more dramatic cases answers can be deleted.

> How many sites take unofficial action on answers without sources (i.e. downvotes, comments linking to a meta answer, etc.)?

+1

> When is it a good idea to transition from taking unofficial action to taking official action on answers without sources?

Depends. This is really a hard question to answer. Some people care about downvotes/comments. Some don't. Some don't care about post notices (you don't get a ping for one as far as I know).

Generally I wait until I see the user has been online a while after a comment/post notice and no action before doing anything officially.

> How much addition work does a sources policy create for moderators?

Depends on how the site feels. Sites should self moderate. Moderators should not be the only ones enforcing this - if anything, moderators should *only* handle the edge cases. Review queues and downvoting/commenting are the easiest way to do this as a site.

There are always people who want to post whatever they want and not post any reasoning/backing. You have to accept this. As a site and moderator you are a teacher and representative, you will encounter this in some fashion and have to gently guide people into that expectation.

Right now, I think minimal work on Workplace. But that's because as a community the site downvotes answers without sources, etc. The initial stages were harder I think (I was a high rep user for much of the time getting the community to support this overall, perhaps an older or ex-moderator can discuss this more detailed for the process of getting there).

> Does a "sources are required" policy significantly increase the quality of answers? In other words, is it worth the time to implement one?

The policy doesn't affect it at all. Site culture does ;)

I would suggest focusing on question quality though, first. Good questions will *tend* to get good answers. Bad questions normally get bad answers.

Requiring sources to be applied when most questions are crap won't be fruitful and will be... painful.

> What are the downsides to a sources-are-required policy?

The entire Internet is a forum. Stack Exchange is not. You will face resistance from people who want a site to be a glorified discussion board. Accept this, and realize you can't please everyone.

The biggest downsides are popular opinions, without any explanation. Such as ["just quit"](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1692/2322) - this might be a popular answer, but on a site like Workplace this has **significant** potential impact to people's lives (adding incorrect code can be undone trivially; unquitting a job cannot).

These are the hard cases. Especially when it's a popular answer that doesn't explain the "why?" or even answer the question..

Answer (score 3):

Here's a list of sites that have sources policies. Please feel free to edit.

### Sites where moderation action is taken against unsourced answers:

- Skeptics (meta post)
- Health ([meta post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/283/920))

### Sites where informal action is taken against unsourced answers:

- Mythology ([meta post](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/264/62))

Comment: I think Parenting has "back it up" policy; IIRC [Workplace](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263795/165773) took it from there. I don't remember details though

Comment: Related: [How widespread is the “back it up” principle?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167259/162102)