# What can I do when my answer is in my opinion unfairly deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-answers

I refer to my answer [on Islam Stackexchange](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25076/12680). My answer got deleted with the comment that I don't meet the questioner's perspective and I was told my answer is anti-slavery rhetoric.

I don't agree with this because I gave a reference to a historical document of recent interest and gave a more or less reasonable distinction between slave and prisoner to make my point.

Did someone have a similar experience?
I don't know how to deal with that. The user has all the privileges and single handedly decided to delete my answer without discussion, warning or prior notice.
That is one of the really frustrating experiences on Stackexchange websites I have to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Raise the issue on your site's meta.  Asking why a question was closed, why something was deleted, whether something can be reopened, etc are all appropriate on per-site metas, where people can address the specifics of the situation.  Most meta sites have tags named things like "specific-question" and "specific-answer" for just this reason.

Sites are allowed to have rules for answers beyond the Stack Exchange baseline.  For example, several sites have variations on the [back-it-up rule](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167259/162102).  Most sites have rules about the scope of an answer matching constraints in the question; if somebody asks for an emacs solution on SO then "use vi" isn't an answer, and on The Workplace "quit your job" is almost never an acceptable answer.  Site-specific policies are usually documented on the per-site meta; look for questions tagged "faq", or ask for clarification.