# This post doesn't cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by

Tags: support, review

I was reviewing Low Quality Posts today and saw this message. Is this something new?

> This post doesn't cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.

[image: This post doesn't cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.]

Comment: Oh my that *is* low quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a [post notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102363/support-for-banners); moderators can add those to posts.

They are canned; moderators choose from a pre-defined list. Their goal is to educate both the author of the post and anyone else thinking about answering the question, to improve the quality of the answers.

Comment: You shouldn't have linked. Then we could have convinced the moderators to place a post notice.