# Where does this "citations" banner come from?

Tags: support, answers, low-quality-posts

I noticed that this answer that was hit with a few down votes had a message beneath it which I haven't seen before. I have looked in the help and can't find anything to state where it came from.

Is it something that a moderator can attach to an answer or does it come from somewhere else?

[image: This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this article by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.]

Comment: [*"Moderators now have the ability to add "notices" on posts"*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107142/161198)

Comment: Next time please *quote* the text you're referring to? Makes it much easier to find, and for the duplicate-finding-algorithm to warn you before even posting. Also, a more descriptive title helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: It means the answer was an opinion, since there was no references to support the argument stated.

Comment: @Arjan But then where would he put the freehand circle?

Comment: True, @Cody, though I still need to see a freehand circle in a title ;-) (Thanks for that alt-text.)