# Can Community help a brother out?

Tags: discussion, moderation, subjective, community-user, not-constructive

And close all questions posted prior to the year 2010 that start with the word "Best" as "Not Constructive?"  Seems like half the flags I see now are about this.  Why not just do it en masse and get it over with?

Comment: Please oh Please, don't do bulk closings like that.  Some of those 'Best' questions have a lot of good answers.  And good answers are the priority.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: This isn't a bulk *deletion*.  They will still remain.  But questions that are concerned about the "Best XYZ to ABC" are ***typically*** not acceptable anymore, and should be closed as "not constructive".

Comment: I'd be fine with that, it's how `close` is supposed to work, except that there are some mods who think that closed questions are just the first step in the deletion process.  How about we `Protect` them?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: That's fine by me.  There are many cases where we need a third way to handle certain situations.  Handling classic questions that are still open yet would not be acceptable if asked today is one of these.  [Perhaps this will play a part in it.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106137/better-handling-of-locked-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Any particular ones you want closed?

Comment: @OffBySome: All of them.  I wish to hear the lamentations of their OPs and answerers.

Comment: @Won't There are 3200+ though. I'd also like to see about 40% of the current Facebook tagged questions closed/deleted.  It's nice to want things :)

Comment: Yes please, also add any question that has the word "favorite" or even "your favorite" in its title.

Comment: Not all questions with the word "best" in them are unconstructive.  Some of them are specific enough to be answerable.

You still need to lay eyes on each one.

Comment: Honestly, I Think a query to close all that match might result in less flags to reopen, than flags we receive to close. Not a bad idea. Seems to me CHAOS might come in handy here, though so there's some review of the results prior to the closing.

Comment: @TimPost: BRING ON THE CHAOS!

Answer (score 18):

**Do not close questions just because their title contains the word *best***. In particular, about half of these are asking for “the best way to do X” and are generally reasonable questions, just formulated in a slightly dodgy way — they should be **edited** to read “how to do X”.

Some expressions are almost always worth killing on sight, such as “best practice(s)”. But not “best” alone.

- [Consider editing “best way” to “how”](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1861/best-way-posts)
- [Consider closing as non-constructive](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1862/best-posts-prior-to-2010)

(queries adapted from [Chris's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106168/can-community-help-a-brother-out/106183#106183))

Comment: In addition, "best practices" tend to refer to what is accepted by a community and therefore can indeed be objective and quite reasonable (although technically I suppose an accepted "best practice" might not be the best practice).

Answer (score 8):

I made a quick [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112570/best-posts-prior-to-2010) for you. This would probably be a good place to start.

Comment: The cynic in me suspects that folks will now quickly flag this list of questions to cash in on flag weight using the incoming tsunami of close votes. :)

Comment: @razlebe: Actually, if multiple people flag it makes the job of closing them pretty easy.  Also, @Chris' query brings back evened the closed ones, which isn't exactly efficient of flagger's time.  Added `ClosedDate is null` and got back 3.5k.  Also closed the most popular result for Python.  Hold fast for s*strom.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `ClosedDate`, @Won't. I've updated the query accordingly.

Comment: @Won't: Good then. :) Cheers

Comment: Uh, I think I derped.  The difference is only 54 questions.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too. Oh well, I still think it makes the query better.

Answer (score 0):

Now that a bunch have been closed, the search box works better until the next data dump update:

[wiki:0 closed:0 title:best](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wiki:0%20closed:0%20title:best)

Same warnings apply (analyze each question to make sure it actually deserves to be closed).