# What flag should 10k users use for old posts now considered not constructive or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've been going through and flagging old posts that are now considered non-constructive or off-topic, using queries from [Can Community help a brother out?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106168/can-community-help-a-brother-out) Since I have more then 10k reputation, my only flag options are "Other" and "Very Low Quality".

If I select "Other" then the flag can only be seen by moderators, which means more work for them. If I select "Very Low Quality" then any 10k users can see it and we can close it without moderator intervention.

So "Very Low Quality" works better, but the questions usually aren't very low quality. Which should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It doesn't belong here" > "Not constructive" is the correct close reason for those, so that's how I'd flag them.

---

As Jeremy explained in his comment below, for 10K mods whose flags are being automatically converted to close votes, it's fine to flag these types of questions as "Other" and write in either "not constructive" or "off-topic" as the close reason.

Comment: @JeremyBanks & Bill: The option appears in the flag menu, but it's silently converted to an ordinary close vote if you have enough rep to cast a close vote and haven't run out of close votes for the day.

Comment: @Gilles So spend all your close votes first. ;)

Comment: @Gilles & Bill: The UI no longer supports this answer; the flags are always converted to close votes (and just fail if you're out of votes for the day). As a workaround I have been typing in "not constructive" as my "other" flag reason. My understanding is that this would be the same as using the predefined flag reason (and would show up in the 10k queue).

Comment: @JeremyBanksʬʬʬ Ah, that explains why we have so many "other" flags lately.  I still get the full UI, so I wasn't clear on the changes.  (Sadly, I'm still not a 10K user on any site where I'm not also a moderator.)  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The discovery that [typing out a canned flag reason equivalent to selecting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119125/is-typing-out-a-canned-flag-reason-equivalent-to-selecting-it) lets us mostly avoid this restriction. The "off topic" flag is still impossible because of the character limit, but "not constructive" and "off topic; belongs on Programmers"  are both available:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have 10k, you have enough reputation to vote to close. When you encounter a question that is not constructive or off-topic, vote to close it. It will then (regardless of its age) go into the Close Votes review queue, where other 3k+ users will get an opportunity to confirm or reject your judgment. You may also downvote the question, and vote to delete it once it is sufficiently downvoted to be eligible for deletion if it has little or no scope for improvement.

Comment: Please reword your answer. Downvoting to make something eligible for deletion is dubious at best. You should only downvote when the posts quality warrants that.